# Heroku — "We're sorry, but something went wrong"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, web-deployment-project

Hi I'm pretty new on Heroku. I have finished part of my app. Currently I'm working locally, but I want to deploy to Heroku. When I typed `heroku logs` I got this:

```
2012-07-30T16:36:27+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style  plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them  out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and  config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this:  http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top  (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-07-30T16:36:27+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style  plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them  out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and  config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this:  http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top  (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-07-30T16:36:30+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-07-30T16:36:30+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:17050
2012-07-30T16:36:30+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-07-30T16:36:30+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-07-30T16:36:30+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2012-07-30T16:36:33+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-07-30 16:36:33] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2012-07-30T16:36:33+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-07-30 16:36:33] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2012-07-30T16:36:33+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-07-30 16:36:33] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=17050
2012-07-30T16:36:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 190.242.128.66 at 2012-07-30  16:36:35 +0000
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 80ms
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.5ms)
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (defaults.js isn't precompiled):
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:     <title>Home</title>
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     <style>
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:       body {
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:         padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___4087131318243872015_49358580'
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 heroku[router]: GET newbies.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=254ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-07-30T16:36:35+00:00 heroku[router]: GET newbies.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=11ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-07-30T17:41:05+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2012-07-30T17:41:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-07-30T17:41:09+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-07-30 17:41:09] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2012-07-30T17:41:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2012-07-30T17:41:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2012-07-30T17:41:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2012-07-30T17:41:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2012-07-30T17:41:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2012-07-30T22:10:05+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
2012-07-30T22:10:05+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:create`
2012-07-30T22:10:05+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-07-30T22:10:11+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-07-30T22:10:11+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
2012-07-30T22:10:24+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2012-07-30T22:10:24+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
2012-07-30T22:10:25+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-07-30T22:10:41+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-07-30T22:10:41+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
2012-07-30T22:10:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2012-07-30T22:10:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2012-07-30T22:10:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 47690`
2012-07-30T22:11:02+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-07-30T22:11:02+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-07-30T22:11:05+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-07-30T22:11:05+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:47690
2012-07-30T22:11:05+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-07-30T22:11:05+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-07-30T22:11:05+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2012-07-30T22:11:08+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-07-30 22:11:08] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2012-07-30T22:11:08+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-07-30 22:11:08] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2012-07-30T22:11:08+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-07-30 22:11:08] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=47690
2012-07-30T22:11:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 190.242.128.66 at 2012-07-30 22:11:10 +0000
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 83ms
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.6ms)
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (defaults.js isn't precompiled):
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:     <title>Home</title>
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     <style>
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:       body {
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:         padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___517725991346781271_49385800'
2012-07-30T22:11:10+00:00 heroku[router]: GET newbies.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=264ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 190.242.128.66 at 2012-07-30 22:12:25 +0000
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (defaults.js isn't precompiled):
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:     <title>Home</title>
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     <style>
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:         padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:       body {
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___517725991346781271_49385800'
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-30T22:12:25+00:00 heroku[router]: GET newbies.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=643
```

And when I type `heroku open` it shows me *"We're sorry, but something went wrong."* Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

assets should be precompiled
add to your config/application.rb

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

more at:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar/

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile your assets locally first.

Take a look here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar

Try the below before pushing to Heroku.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: After you compile your assets, you need to make sure they're added into your Git stage for pushing to Heroku.  Try `git add -A` to add all newly created files.

Answer (score 0):

1. migrate the database on server.
2. try precompiling your asset pipeline

Answer (score 0):

When you create your heroku stack do this instead of just heroku create:

```
heroku create --stack cedar
```

and make sure you do this before you push to heroku:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```