# "We're sorry, but something went wrong." Database-migration (Heroku, Git Bash)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, postgresql, heroku, database-migration

Hi everyone in this forum! :)
I'm new here, so forgive for the mistakes I made or the noobish questions I may ask. I'm also new to programming too, so please be patient :) I learn Ruby on Rails, and try to get my app running on the web with Heroku. But no matter how hard I try, I can't get it to work properly.

So the problem is: 
I get an error message when I check my app on the web saying:

**"We're sorry, but something went wrong"**

I have read about this problem (on the "theodinproject" website), and it is connected with **database migration** -from what I've understood.

*I am using:
PostgreSQL 9.4 ///
Git 1.9.5-preview20141217*

Still, I do not know how to proceed. Please help me.

(the code I attached is not complete, but I hope you can find the mistake(s) in it.

```
remote:        Warning. Error encountered while saving cache /tmp/build_7fe80551
4c65f55b3e7c6ffbf5a1e179/tmp/cache/sass/074cffc5affa5c84b781ae2423063506c85d58b1
/home.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f71296b1a38>
remote:        DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/p
lugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out an
d bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and
config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http:/
/weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from
<top (required)> at /tmp/build_7fe805514c65f55b3e7c6ffbf5a1e179/Rakefile:7)
remote:        DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/p
lugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out an
d bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and
config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http:/
/weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from
<top (required)> at /tmp/build_7fe805514c65f55b3e7c6ffbf5a1e179/Rakefile:7)
remote:        Warning. Error encountered while saving cache /tmp/build_7fe80551
4c65f55b3e7c6ffbf5a1e179/tmp/cache/sass/074cffc5affa5c84b781ae2423063506c85d58b1
/home.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f3974848550>
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (10.78s)
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Injecting plugin 'rails_log_stdout'
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Injecting plugin 'rails3_serve_static_assets'
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Add 'rails_12factor' gem to your Gemfile to skip plugin injection

remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
remote:        To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
remote:        ruby '2.0.0'
remote:        # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for mor
e information.
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properl
y.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app
.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your depende
ncies at all.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote:        Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 26.1MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v6
remote:        https://peaceful-gorge-9214.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/peaceful-gorge-9214.git
* [new branch]      master -> master

Abel@ABEL-PC /c/Sites/myrubyblog (master)
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.1040
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support
for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them i
n your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initial
izers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonr
ails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required
)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support
for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them i
n your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initial
izers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonr
ails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required
)> at /app/Rakefile:7)

Abel@ABEL-PC /c/Sites/myrubyblog (master)
$ git push heroku master
Everything up-to-date

Abel@ABEL-PC /c/Sites/myrubyblog (master)
$ git push heroku master
Everything up-to-date

Abel@ABEL-PC /c/Sites/myrubyblog (master)
$ heroku create --stack cedar
!    You've reached the limit of 5 apps for unverified accounts.
!    Delete some apps or add a credit card to verify your account.

Abel@ABEL-PC /c/Sites/myrubyblog (master)
$ git push heroku master
Everything up-to-date

Abel@ABEL-PC /c/Sites/myrubyblog (master)
$ heroku logs -t
←[36m2015-04-22T06:12:48.946759+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     2: <html>
←[36m2015-04-22T06:12:48.946766+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tag
s %>
←[36m2015-04-22T06:12:48.946755+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-04-22T06:12:48.946768+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/views/layouts/applic
ation.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__456807460569566140
5_70045134083880'
←[36m2015-04-22T06:12:48.946767+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     8: </head>
←[36m2015-04-22T06:12:48.946769+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-04-22T06:12:48.946758+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionView::Template::Erro
r (default.css isn't precompiled):
←[36m2015-04-22T06:12:48.946763+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     5:   <%= stylesheet_li
nk_tag    "default", :media => "all" %>
←[36m2015-04-22T06:12:48.935846+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by HomeControll
er#index as HTML
←[36m2015-04-22T06:12:48.944757+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Ser
ver Error in 8.7ms
←[36m2015-04-22T06:12:48.946771+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[33m2015-04-22T06:12:49.528519+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h="/favicon.ico" host=peaceful-gorge-9214.herokuapp.com request_id=f203763b-250a
-41c9-b525-a0ad82f88f91 fwd="193.6.168.41" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms s
tatus=200 bytes=323
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:53.352805+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Idling
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:53.354125+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from up t
o down
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:56.808445+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping all processes
with SIGTERM
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603395+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-22 07:16:57] FATA
L SignalException: SIGTERM
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603403+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/l
ib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603400+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/l
ib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603405+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/l
ib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603406+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603408+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603410+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603412+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)
>'
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603413+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603402+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/l
ib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603414+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603416+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   script/rails:6:in `requi
re'
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603418+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   script/rails:6:in `<main
>'
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603423+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-22 07:16:57] INFO
  going to shutdown ...
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603447+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-22 07:16:57] INFO
  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:57.603466+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Exiting
←[36m2015-04-22T07:16:58.823388+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with sta
tus 143
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:04.595881+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Unidling
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:04.596062+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from down
to starting
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:09.277085+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with c
ommand `bundle exec rails server -p 25616`
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:13.426726+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEPRECATION WARNING: You h
ave Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be
removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold th
em in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the
release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-
2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environm
ent.rb:5)
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:13.426264+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEPRECATION WARNING: You h
ave Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be
removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold th
em in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the
release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-
2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environm
ent.rb:5)
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:14.192475+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from star
ting to up
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:14.128069+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-22 14:22:14] INFO
  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=25616
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:14.127733+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-22 14:22:14] INFO
  WEBrick 1.3.1
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:14.127750+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-22 14:22:14] INFO
  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:16.671964+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Booting WEBrick
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:16.671977+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 193.6.
168.230 at 2015-04-22 14:22:16 +0000
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:16.890280+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Connecting to database spe
cified by DATABASE_URL
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:16.671971+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Rails 3.2.21 applicatio
n starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:25616
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:16.671973+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Call with -d to detach
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:16.671975+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Ctrl-C to shutdown serv
er
←[33m2015-04-22T14:22:17.121875+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h="/" host=peaceful-gorge-9214.herokuapp.com request_id=27cc842d-97c4-41ee-bb1b-
c5414df2c851 fwd="193.6.168.230" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=467ms status=500
bytes=939
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:17.114423+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Ser
ver Error in 8.5ms
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:17.105805+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by HomeControll
er#index as HTML
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:17.112211+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered home/index.html
.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:17.116354+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:17.116358+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionView::Template::Erro
r (default.css isn't precompiled):
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:17.116361+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     3: <head>
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:17.116363+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     4:   <title>Myrubyblog
</title>
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:17.116360+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     2: <html>
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:17.116366+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     6:   <%= javascript_in
clude_tag "default" %>
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:17.116364+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     5:   <%= stylesheet_li
nk_tag    "default", :media => "all" %>
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:17.116367+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tag
s %>
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:17.116371+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/views/layouts/applic
ation.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__451241027198694938
9_70288888574320'
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:17.116372+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:17.116373+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-04-22T14:22:17.116369+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     8: </head>
←[33m2015-04-22T14:25:48.363056+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h="/" host=peaceful-gorge-9214.herokuapp.com request_id=d1ad96f9-4292-4bf9-a1a3-
e5f3b0b0b8cc fwd="193.6.168.230" dyno=web.1 connect=10ms service=23ms status=500
bytes=939
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.343740+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by HomeControll
er#index as HTML
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.345506+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Ser
ver Error in 1.7ms
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.344585+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered home/index.html
.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.347216+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionView::Template::Erro
r (default.css isn't precompiled):
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.347220+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     3: <head>
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.347224+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     5:   <%= stylesheet_li
nk_tag    "default", :media => "all" %>
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.347213+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.340679+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 193.6.
168.230 at 2015-04-22 14:25:48 +0000
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.347221+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     4:   <title>Myrubyblog
</title>
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.347218+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     2: <html>
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.347225+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     6:   <%= javascript_in
clude_tag "default" %>
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.347227+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tag
s %>
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.347228+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     8: </head>
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.347230+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/views/layouts/applic
ation.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__451241027198694938
9_70288888574320'
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.347232+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-04-22T14:25:48.347233+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[33m2015-04-22T14:25:49.604725+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h="/favicon.ico" host=peaceful-gorge-9214.herokuapp.com request_id=58ce9665-d914
-4f4b-a0d5-1330b6d13f95 fwd="193.6.168.230" dyno=web.1 connect=13ms service=124m
s status=304 bytes=153
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:04.803632+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Idling
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:04.804237+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from up t
o down
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:07.878185+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping all processes
with SIGTERM
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617094+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/l
ib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617110+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617112+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   script/rails:6:in `requi
re'
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617113+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   script/rails:6:in `<main
>'
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617107+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)
>'
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617098+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/l
ib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617202+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-22 15:29:08] INFO
  going to shutdown ...
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617297+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-22 15:29:08] INFO
  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617376+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Exiting
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617101+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617108+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617099+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/l
ib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617103+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617105+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617096+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/l
ib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:08.617089+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-04-22 15:29:08] FATA
L SignalException: SIGTERM
←[36m2015-04-22T15:29:09.777442+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with sta
tus 143
```

And here you can find the build log of my app on Heroku:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.7.12
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
       Resolving dependencies...
       Using rake 10.4.2
       Using i18n 0.7.0
       Using builder 3.0.4
       Using erubis 2.7.0
       Using multi_json 1.11.0
       Using journey 1.0.4
       Using rack 1.4.5
       Using hike 1.2.3
       Using tilt 1.4.1
       Using mime-types 1.25.1
       Using polyglot 0.3.5
       Using arel 3.0.3
       Using tzinfo 0.3.43
       Using bundler 1.7.12
       Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
       Using execjs 2.5.2
       Using json 1.8.2
       Using thor 0.19.1
       Using pg 0.18.1
       Using sass 3.4.13
       Using rack-cache 1.2
       Using rack-test 0.6.3
       Using rack-ssl 1.3.4
       Using treetop 1.4.15
       Using activesupport 3.2.21
       Using sprockets 2.2.3
       Using rdoc 3.12.2
       Using mail 2.5.4
       Using activemodel 3.2.21
       Using activerecord 3.2.21
       Using activeresource 3.2.21
       Using actionpack 3.2.21
       Using actionmailer 3.2.21
       Using railties 3.2.21
       Using rails 3.2.21
       Using sass-rails 3.2.6
       Using jquery-rails 3.1.2
       Using coffee-script 2.4.1
       Using coffee-rails 3.2.2
       Using uglifier 2.7.1
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (27.09s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_62b0729b72e189f39d2719f5a6a39ffb/Rakefile:7)
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_62b0729b72e189f39d2719f5a6a39ffb/Rakefile:7)
       Warning. Error encountered while saving cache /tmp/build_62b0729b72e189f39d2719f5a6a39ffb/tmp/cache/sass/fa3b46a24cd2ed44f3a4308a38aea27e493d00ff/home.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f2f15396c28>
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_62b0729b72e189f39d2719f5a6a39ffb/Rakefile:7)
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_62b0729b72e189f39d2719f5a6a39ffb/Rakefile:7)
       Warning. Error encountered while saving cache /tmp/build_62b0729b72e189f39d2719f5a6a39ffb/tmp/cache/sass/fa3b46a24cd2ed44f3a4308a38aea27e493d00ff/home.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f0e74274668>
       Asset precompilation completed (15.30s)
###### WARNING:
       Injecting plugin 'rails_log_stdout'
###### WARNING:
       Injecting plugin 'rails3_serve_static_assets'
###### WARNING:
       Add 'rails_12factor' gem to your Gemfile to skip plugin injection
###### WARNING:
       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
       ruby '2.0.0'
       # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
###### WARNING:
       No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker
-----> Compressing... done, 26.2MB
-----> Launching... done, v7
       https://peaceful-gorge-9214.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

I have already checked these discussions:

[Heroku — "We're sorry, but something went wrong"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742617/heroku-were-sorry-but-something-went-wrong)

[Rails 2.3-style plugins and deprecation warnings running task in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027403/rails-2-3-style-plugins-and-deprecation-warnings-running-task-in-heroku)

http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/deployment

Comment: How are you including default.css?

Comment: Are you using a cache store?

Comment: I don't know if I am including default.css, or using a cache store. 
How do I know if I do? What does it influence?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your migration actually ran. There should be some output from running `heroku run rake db:migrate` after the `Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.1040` and those depreciation warnings.

Check on your db schema to verify that your migrations ran on your database. Open up the Postgres console with `run heroku pg:psql`, then `\d tablename` to check your schema. I'd also check your database config file (config/database.yml) to make sure the production db is set up correctly for postgres.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.

The database.yml file is ok, I think. The adapter is "postgresql", the database name, the user and pass is also good. And they are all the same for development, test and production.

But I could not do what you said about the Postgres console. How do I exactly get that console? I tried from the Git Bash (I did everything in that one, so, I tried) but it didn't work.

Thank you for your help, and please be patient, I'm an enthousiast with zero experience. But I am willing to learn =)